# Run Javascript after JSON load

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

I am trying to run some javascript after the data from JSON has successfully loaded so I can then manipulate my dom elements, but having trouble accomplishing this as when I run my javascript, the elements are not loaded yet.

```
app.controller('portfolioController', function($scope, $route, $http) {
 $scope.contents = null;
  $http.get("js/json/portfolio.json").success(function(data) {
    $scope.contents = data;
    alert('alert this after all elements are loaded on dom');
  });
});

<ul class="projects basic" >
    <li ng-repeat="content in contents">
        <img src="img/projects/{{ content.image }} " >
        <a class="hover" ></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up using the `ng-click` directive on my dom, then called in the click function, which worked great. Here is updated code:

```
app.controller('portfolioController', function($scope, $route, $http) {
  $scope.classes = 'basic about';

  $scope.contents = null;

  $http.get("js/json/portfolio.json").success(function(data) {
    $scope.contents = data;
  });

  $scope.showDetails = function() {
    alert('do stuff after everything is loaded');
  }

});

<ul class="projects basic" >
    <li ng-repeat="content in contents">
        <img ng-src="img/projects/{{ content.image }} " >
        <a ng-click="showDetails()" class="hover" ></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```